# How do you make a bot set the slowmode for a channel in discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do you make a bot set the slow mode for a channel in `discord.py` rewrite?

I tried doing this: `ctx.channel.slowmode_delay = 10`

It didn't get any error, but when I called the above command the slowmode was not applied.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def setdelay(ctx, seconds: int):
    await ctx.channel.edit(slowmode_delay=seconds)
    await ctx.send(f"Set the slowmode delay in this channel to {seconds} seconds!")
```

---

**References:**

- [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)
- [`Context.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.channel)
- [`TextChannel.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.edit) - setting the delay to 0 will disable slowmode.